# How to split a data frame column based on equal length into separate rows in R

Tags: r, strsplit

[image]

Any help will be appreciated, Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one base R option

```
f <- function(v) Map(intToUtf8,split(utf8ToInt(v),ceiling(seq(nchar(v))/2)))
q <- Vectorize(f)(mydf$V2)
p <- rep(mydf$V1,lengths(q))
mydfout <- data.frame(V1 = p,V2 = unlist(q),row.names = NULL)
```

which gives

```
> mydfout
   V1 V2
1   1 ab
2   1 cd
3   1 ef
4   2 ab
5   2 cd
6   3 bg
7   3 hj
8   4 kl
9   5 ui
10  5 lm
```

**Data**

```
mydf <- structure(list(V1 = 1:5, V2 = c("abcdef", "abcd", "bghj", "kl", 
"uilm")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -5L))
```